# О слове "много"

Tags: морфология

К какой части речи можно отнести слово "много" в словосочетании "знает много языков" или  "знаком со многими людьми"?

Comment: По моему мнению, "много" и "мало" - это обобщённые натуральные числа, а именно подмножества {2, 3, 4, ...} и {0, 1} соответственно (см. мой вопрос "Что такое "много" и "мало" с точки зрения математика?" в разделе "Математика").

Если я прав, тогда словосочетание "знает много языков" равнозначно словосочетаниям "знает по меньшей мере два языка", "знает два или более языков", "знает не меньше, чем два языка", "знает {2, 3, 4, ...} языков".

Answer (score 2):

"знает много языков" .Знает что?-много языков - слитное сочетание, где много- количественное наречие.

"знаком со многими людьми". С кем?-с людьми. С какими?-многими- относительное прилагательное, обозначающее признак предмета через отношение к количеству,числу, так же как прилагательное двойной, тройной.

Answer (score 0):

многие - местоименное прилагательное; много - предполагаю, что наречие, но в значении числительного.

Comment: Наречие обозначает признак действия. В этих словосочетаниях его нет. И с прилагательным как-то не могу согласиться. Мне почему-то кажется, что это какая-то разновидность числительного. Количественно-неопределенного...

Comment: Ученые спорят по поводу слова много.  Действительно, принято считать его наречием. Впрочем, без особых на то оснований. Но пока ученые спорят, должно же как-то называть. Вот и остановились на наречии.

 Почитайте здесь,вовсе не официальное мнение, но интересно.[link text][1]


  [1]: http://rus-exam.ru/blog/item/148-2012-mnogo-vazshnogo